# Data Merge 7 barcodes on 1 page 4000 times

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-production, indesign-scripting

I have to place 7 different barcodes on to 1 page but then they run 4000 times sequentially.

I tried to use scripts such as ImagesToCSV, but the images don't link when merged.

Other option is to MultiPageImport script for individual artwork then interleave and N-UP the artwork to 1 page but takes forever to do just 10.

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: More information is needed here – what exactly do you mean by “run 4000 times sequentially”? Do you just want 4,000 identical pages with the seven barcodes in the same places on each page? What’s sequential about that? Or is it something else you’re after? What format should you end up with – a PDF file? An InDesign document you can continue working in? Something else?

Comment: So it's an event running for 7 days, every day you need a different pass hence why there is 7 on a sheet as this is given to each person. Every barcode is a different and in a Code 128 format.

Comment: For example the barcodes on page one are GLFR000000001, GLFB000000001, GLFY000000001, GLFG000000001, GLFE000000001, GLFO000000001, GLFP000000001 (first three characters fixed, 4th character is the colour of the respective pass, followed by sequential numbering - 4000 as that many passes being issued)

Comment: The next page would be GLFR000000002, GLFB000000002, GLFY000000002, GLFG000000002, GLFE000000002, GLFO000000002, GLFP000000002.

Comment: The artwork remains the same for all 4000 sheets, the barcode changes for each one on every sheet so none are identical. We are printing these in house

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. So essentially it would be 28,000 unique barcodes. I think the easiest way to do that would probably be to use a barcode font and script the insertion of the appropriate text – set up your artwork and text frames on a master page, set up paragraph styles properly, and you can automate it with a few clicks.

Comment: Thank you will have a hunt now for a apporpriate font to suit

Comment: There are several EAN fonts available which I usually use for barcodes – they work very well in my experience.

Comment: So I needed it to be Code 128 format as opposed to EAN 13. I just remembered I done a job like this a few years back and purchased a font family called ID Automation. Just done a test run and worked a treat! Thanks for your help